# R function to search in character string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this
[image]

Now When I am loading this dataframe in R I want something like this

when a number in NAICS_CD col is present in top_3 , I need is_present col as 1 else 0
I need this to be done with R programming
[image]

Answer (score 3):

We could use `str_detect` from `stringr` package together with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(is_present = ifelse(str_detect(top_3, as.character(NAICS_CD)), 1, 0))
```

```
  NAICS_CD                        top_3 is_present
1   541611 ["541611","541618","611430"]          1
2   812990 ["561720","561740","561790"]          0
3   424950 ["444120","711510","811121"]          0
4   722330 ["311991","722310","722320"]          0
5   722320 ["722320","722330","722310"]          1
6   531180 ["531110","531190","531111"]          0
7   484121 ["484121","484110","484230"]          1
8   531311 ["531110","531311","531111"]          1
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(NAICS_CD = c(541611L, 812990L, 424950L, 722330L, 
722320L, 531180L, 484121L, 531311L), top_3 = c("[\"541611\",\"541618\",\"611430\"]", 
"[\"561720\",\"561740\",\"561790\"]", "[\"444120\",\"711510\",\"811121\"]", 
"[\"311991\",\"722310\",\"722320\"]", "[\"722320\",\"722330\",\"722310\"]", 
"[\"531110\",\"531190\",\"531111\"]", "[\"484121\",\"484110\",\"484230\"]", 
"[\"531110\",\"531311\",\"531111\"]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl` to check whether any pattern (in this case any targeted number) is present or not in the targeted row, and then use `any` to return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` to be suitable with conditional `ifelse`. Then, use `ifelse` to assign `1` or `0` to `is_present` column.
For example:

```
top3_row1 <-'["541611", "541618","611430"]'
is_present <- ifelse(any(grepl("54161", top3_row1)), 1, 0)
is_present
[1] 1
```

To apply this to your data frame, you can use `for` loop or other ways. For example:

```
for(k in 1:nrow(mydf)){
mydf$is_present[k] <- ifelse(any(grepl(mydf$NAICS_CD[k], mydf$top_3)), 1, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `mapply` one-liner. Fully vectorized, no need for `ifelse`.

```
mapply(\(x, y) as.integer(grepl(x, y)), df$NAICS_CD, df$top_3)
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
```

And assign to the new column.

```
df$is_present <- mapply(\(x, y) as.integer(grepl(x, y)), df$NAICS_CD, df$top_3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R:

```
transform(df, present = +Vectorize(grepl)(NAICS_CD, top_3))

  NAICS_CD                        top_3 present
1   541611 ["541611","541618","611430"]       1
2   812990 ["561720","561740","561790"]       0
3   424950 ["444120","711510","811121"]       0
4   722330 ["311991","722310","722320"]       0
5   722320 ["722320","722330","722310"]       1
6   531180 ["531110","531190","531111"]       0
7   484121 ["484121","484110","484230"]       1
8   531311 ["531110","531311","531111"]       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `mapply` + `regmatches`

```
transform(
    df,
    present = +mapply(
        `%in%`,
        NAICS_CD,
        regmatches(top_3, gregexpr("\\w+", top_3))
    )
)
```

gives

```
  NAICS_CD                        top_3 present
1   541611 ["541611","541618","611430"]       1
2   812990 ["561720","561740","561790"]       0
3   424950 ["444120","711510","811121"]       0
4   722330 ["311991","722310","722320"]       0
5   722320 ["722320","722330","722310"]       1
6   531180 ["531110","531190","531111"]       0
7   484121 ["484121","484110","484230"]       1
8   531311 ["531110","531311","531111"]       1
```